# Projection of a SpatialPixelsDataFrame objects

Tags: map-projections

I have created SpatialPixelsDataFrame objects from Raster files. But I cannot work it along with my SpatialPintsDataFrame object. I got this error message:
Error in count.points(GPSLocs, Grass) : different proj4string in w and xy
which means the SpatialPixelsDataFrame objects do not have a projection defined.

GPSLocs= SpatialPointsDataFrame object
Grass= SpatialPixelsDataFrame object

Any suggestions of how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "different proj4string in w and xy" suggest that the coordinate reference systems are different (it *may* be that one of them is undefined). For others to be able to help you, should always show some code or data. For example what you get when you do:

```
library(raster)
w
xy
# or
crs(w)
crs(xy)
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it fixed by saving the shape file in QGIS with a proper extent. The projections were similar but there was a problem with the extents. I did it manually in QGIS.